# Reading from a file with a scanner in Java

Tags: java, file

In this assignment we're suppose to read test and homework scores from a txt file and compute a final grade. Since we haven't learned about reading and writing files, this is the premade method given to us:

```
/******************************************************************************
 *
 * Filename :     GradeCalculatorFromFile.java.
 * Author:        xxxxxxxxx
 * Date:          09/025/2011
 * Description:  This program computes the scores of a list of students in the CSE155a class
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

/* Provide a description of the class */
public class GradeCalculatorFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare and initialise the variables as needed
        int anthonyHopkinsTest = 0;
        int anthonyHopkinsHomework = 0;

        /*
         * The following code enables the user to accept input from the
         * keyboard. Keep this code as it is.
         */
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file. Please make sure that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        /*
         * Add your code here to read the number of students and the scores Use
         * scanner.next() to read a String Use scanner.nextInt() to read an int
         */
    }
}
```

And this is the txt file we are suppose to use:

```
4
Anthony Hopkins 80  90  95  87  80  78  25  17  20  22  21  24  19  22  21  23  24  21  20  25  20  55  56  110 30  20  25  8
John    Smith   99  95  82  72  64  52  15  14  11  21  25  12  19  20  21  23  21  12  12  10  15  50  50  60  25  15  20  9
Pan     Mei     85  92  72  45  82  78  22  13  16  22  24  10  18  12  21  24  25  10  11  14  20  58  51  95  28  14  28  7
Rafael  Vega    99  45  87  52  87  99  25  25  21  21  14  19  19  25  25  20  20  18  20  24  20  60  60  60  25  16  23  8
```

The problem is we weren't taught how get information from the file. The instructions say to use the scanner to get the grade, but I have no idea how to do that. The first 21 numbers in a group are homework, the next 3 are test, and the last 4 are homework again. I know how to do this sort of thing with user input, but not when reading the info from a file

Comment: Same thing from file as from user input.

Comment: So do you mean something like anthonyHopkinsHomework = scanner.nextInt()? and then some sort of for loop to add on to his score?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I tried this: `anthonyHopkinsTest = scanner.nextInt();

  for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

   System.out.println(anthonyHopkinsTest);

  }` and got 4 several times. I got it to read, which is pretty cool. How to I chose which line to read from?

Comment: Check the java docs for scanner.